# How can I speed up rate at which dock appears on second screen?

Tags: macos, dock

How do I speed up the time it takes for the dock to appear on a second screen in Mavericks?

At the moment it takes over a second when I've been using it on the first screen then go to use it on the second.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this in your terminal.

```
 defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-time-modifier -float 0.3; killall Dock;
```

Where the number `0.3` is, you can insert the number of seconds you want the animation to take. I found 0.3 to be quick enough, but still provide a nice effect.

P.S. grabbing this from Col1107's answer. Just wanted it saved.

Comment: I think it worth mentioning that you cannot set the delay to 0. Setting the delay to zero appears to have no effect. The delay needs to be greater than zero, even if it's 0.01.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [this website](http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/category-terminal.php) it helped me.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Will do next time. This was my first post so I didn't know the rules. Is there a page with the guidelines/rules I can take a look at?

Comment: Yep, the [about](http://apple.stackexchange.com/about) page and [help center](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help). Welcome to Ask Different by the way!